# Oracle SQL: Handle with Daylight Saving Time

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have the following system information:

I use Oracle Database 10g
The `SysTimeStamp` is `UTC`
The `SessionTimeZone` is `Europe/Athens`
The `dbTimeZone` is `+03:00`

So, I have the column `date_1` from `tbl_1` table, with the following datetime:

```
date_1
-----------------
08.02.2017 10:00
08.02.2017 11:00
08.02.2017 12:00
-----------------
```

The results I want is like this:

```
date_2
-----------------
08.02.2017 13:00
08.02.2017 14:00
08.02.2017 15:00
```

For that I use:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_1 + INTERVAL '3' HOUR, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as date_2 
FROM tbl_1
WHERE date_1 >= TO_DATE('08.02.2017 10:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')
  AND date_1 <= TO_DATE('08.02.2017 12:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')
```

My problem appear when the hour from `March` and `October` is changing because in the last Sunday from `March` we have 23 hours in a day and in the last Sunday from `October` we have 25 hours in a day.

Because of this I have to change my query 4 times/year (On summer time, on winter time, when we have 23 hour in  March and when we have 25 hour in October)

Can you recommend a query in this `select` that solve this problem?

Comment: Why the postgresql tag? Aren't you using Oracle?

Comment: What data type is the `date_1` column, and what time zone are the values it contains nominally in?

Comment: @Alex Poole The type of `date_1` is `DATE`, and the time zone is`Europe/Athens`

Comment: @Marius - if it's stored as a date then it doesn't have any time zone built-in. And if it is already in local (Athens) time, why do you need or want to modify it again? Are you changing it from Athens to a different time zone; or is it stored as +3:00 and you want to adjust to take DST into account (which doesn't match the data/output)? Or something else? Maybe doesn't matter if the answer helped you anyway, but might be useful for future visitors to have the full picture.

Comment: @Alex Poole `date_1` is stored as a `Date` and it has a time zone, which is: `Europe/Athens`

Comment: To view `date_1` I use:   `SELECT TO_CHAR(date_1,  'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') FROM tbl_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a plain date or timestamp with no embedded time zone information, you can tell Oracle to treat it as being in a specific time zone with [the `from_tz()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions077.htm#SQLRF00644). You can then convert that value - which now has data type 'timestamp with zone zone' rather than a plain 'timestamp' - to another zone with the [`at time zone` datetime expression syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions007.htm#SQLRF00401), either using the session time zone as 'local' or with a specific named time zone:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR';
alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';

with cte (ts) as (
  select timestamp '2017-02-08 12:00:00' from dual
)
select ts,
  from_tz(ts, 'UTC') as ts_utc,
  from_tz(ts, 'UTC') at local as ts_local,
  from_tz(ts, 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Athens' as ts_athens
from cte;

TS                  TS_UTC                  TS_LOCAL                             TS_ATHENS                        
------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------
2017-02-08 12:00:00 2017-02-08 12:00:00 UTC 2017-02-08 07:00:00 AMERICA/NEW_YORK 2017-02-08 14:00:00 EUROPE/ATHENS
```

If you're starting from a date then you have to convert it to a timestamp before calling `from_tz()`:

```
with cte (dt) as (
  select cast( timestamp '2017-02-08 12:00:00' as date) from dual
)
select dt,
  from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'UTC') as ts_utc,
  from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'UTC') at local as ts_local,
  from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Athens' as ts_athens
from cte;

DT                  TS_UTC                  TS_LOCAL                             TS_ATHENS                        
------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------
2017-02-08 12:00:00 2017-02-08 12:00:00 UTC 2017-02-08 07:00:00 AMERICA/NEW_YORK 2017-02-08 14:00:00 EUROPE/ATHENS
```

So the data type of your original `date_1` values matters, as does the nominal time zone it is supposed to represent. If it's a;ready a 'timestamp with time zone' or 'timestamp with local time zone' then it already has embedded time zone information, so you don't need the `from_tz()` part at all. If it's a date you need to convert it to a timestamp.

Assuming that `date_1` is stored as a plain timestamp (maybe implied by your interval addition, but not by the column name and filters you used) and that it's nominally UTC, you could do:

```
from_tz(date_1, 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Athens'
```

... which will give you a 'timestamp with time zone' result; or you could use `local` to rely on your session time zone. If `date_1 is stored as a date you'd add the conversion to timestamp:

```
from_tz(cast(date_1 as timestamp), 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Athens'
```

As a demo, generating timestamps (not dates) in a CTE including some around the DST change for this year:

```
with tbl_1(date_1) as (
  select timestamp '2017-02-08 10:00:00' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2017-02-08 11:00:00' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2017-02-08 12:00:00' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2017-03-23 12:00:00' + numtodsinterval(level, 'day')
    from dual connect by level <= 4
)
select date_1,
--  cast(from_tz(date_1, 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Athens' as timestamp) as date_2
  to_char(from_tz(date_1, 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Athens',
    'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as date_2
from tbl_1
order by date_1;

DATE_1              DATE_2          
------------------- ----------------
2017-02-08 10:00:00 08.02.2017 12:00
2017-02-08 11:00:00 08.02.2017 13:00
2017-02-08 12:00:00 08.02.2017 14:00
2017-03-24 12:00:00 24.03.2017 14:00
2017-03-25 12:00:00 25.03.2017 14:00
2017-03-26 12:00:00 26.03.2017 15:00
2017-03-27 12:00:00 27.03.2017 15:00
```

You can see that an extra hour is added automatically after the clocks change on March 26th. But the results are out by an hour for your sample February data - so either your data isn't actually stored as UTC (but is -01:00, and you can change the `from_tz()` call to reflect that), or your expected results are wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! Your your explanation helps me very much in what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a case to the select:

```
select date_1 + case
                  when to_char(date_1 ,'MM') <= 3 then 2/24 -- Jan/Feb/Mar
                  when to_char(date_1,'MM') <= 10 then 3/24 -- Apr to Oct
                  else 2/24 -- Nov/Dec
                end as date_2
from tbl_1
```

Answer (score 0):

### For USA timezone

```
SELECT SYSDATE, 
NEXT_DAY ( TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/03/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM') - 1, 'SUN') + 7 dst_start, 
NEXT_DAY ( TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/11/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM') - 1, 'SUN') dst_end, 
CASE WHEN SYSDATE >= NEXT_DAY ( TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/03/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM') - 1, 'SUN') + 7 AND SYSDATE < NEXT_DAY ( TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/11/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM') - 1, 'SUN') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS dst_check_usa, 
NEW_TIME ( SYSDATE, CASE WHEN SYSDATE >= NEXT_DAY ( TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/03/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM') - 1, 'SUN') + 7 AND SYSDATE < NEXT_DAY ( TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/11/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM') - 1, 'SUN') THEN 'CDT' ELSE 'CST' END, 'GMT') AS current_time_gmt 
FROM DUAL;
```

### For Europe Timezone

```
SELECT SYSDATE, 
NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/03/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM'))-7, 'SUN') dst_start_uk,
NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/10/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM'))-7, 'SUN') dst_end_uk,
CASE WHEN SYSDATE >= NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/03/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM'))-7, 'SUN') AND SYSDATE < NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '/10/01 02:00 AM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI AM'))-7, 'SUN') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS dst_check_uk
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: you need to explain this complicated query in your answer and improve its formatting :)